# Find the generic method on a static class

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I have a class

```
public static class MyClass
{

    public static T MyMethod<T>(T item) where T : ISomeInterface<T>, new
    {
        return MyMethod(new[] { item}).First();
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> MyMethod<T>(params T[] items) where T : ISomeInterface<T>, new
    {
         // for simplicity
         return items.ToList();
    }
}
```

and a bunch of even more complex overloads.
Now I want to extend the class (because I want to call if from powershell) with

```
    public static IEnumerable MyMethod(string typeName, params object[] items)
    {
        var type = Type.GetType(typeName, true, true);
        var paramTypes = new Type[] { type.MakeArrayType() };
        var method = typeof(MyClass).GetMethod(
            "MyMethod", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static
                | BindingFlags.IgnoreCase, null, paramTypes, null);
        return method.Invoke(null, new object[] { items });
    }
```

But `method` is always null. Which is the correct way to get my specific method via `GetMethod()`.

Comment: What is the `table` variable? Do you mean `typeName` instead?

Comment: Are these methods instance methods or static methods?

Comment: `cannot declare instance members in a static class`.

Comment: When you call the method what is the value for `typeName` ?

Comment: Sorry, has some errors after streamlining my productivity code. Of course these are static methods and I eventually use `Type.GetType(...)` to get my type instance which works as expected.

Comment: Also, `method.Invoke` returns an object, not an `IEnumerable`, so this code won't even compile.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that you can use `GetMethod` to search for a generic method (I am not sure though). However, you can use `GetMethods` to get all methods and then filter them like this:

```
var method = typeof (MyClass)
    .GetMethods(
        BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static )
    .Single(x => x.Name == "MyMethod"
        && x.IsGenericMethod
        && x.ReturnType == typeof(IEnumerable<>)
                          .MakeGenericType(x.GetGenericArguments()[0]));
```

Please note that the last condition is checking that the return type of the method is `IEnumerable<T>` so that we don't get the method that returns `T` instead.

Please note that you can cache the `method` variable as a static variable so that you don't have to search for it every time.

Please note that the returned method is still open (It is still `MyMethod<T>`). You still need to create a closed version by calling `MakeGenericMethod` on the method like this:

```
var closed_method = method.MakeGenericMethod(type);
```

You can then invoke it like this:

```
return (IEnumerable)closed_method.Invoke(null, new object[] { items });
```

Comment: I suggest to use LINQs Single method instead of First, especially in a reflection context like this.

Comment: @thehennyy, right. We want to fail if there are multiple methods with the same criteria.